# C++ Builder and chm help file

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, chm

I'm trying to implement CHM help file into my app written in C++ Builder but I always get "no context-sensitive help installed".

I added these lines:

```
#include "HtmlHelpViewer.hpp"
```

OnCreate.. (Form1)

```
Application->HelpFile = ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName) + "myfile.chm";
```

I've set HelpContext via object inspector and also tried manually to call

```
Application->HelpContext(170);
```

But, it's not working. What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to force the linker to include the code. It's not enough just to include the header file.

Try adding this to your code:

```
#include "HTMLHelpViewer.hpp"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "HTMLHelpViewer"
```

I'm assuming that you don't need to add the `Vcl` unit scope name since you did not do so in the code in the question. But if you did need to do that the code would look like this:

```
#include "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer.hpp"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer"
```

---

Judging by your comments, and this [Embarcadero forum thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=413904), I suspect that you are using a version that requires unit scope names. You probably have specified unit scope aliases that mean you can omit the unit scope name in the header file `#include`. But it seems that you cannot omit the unit scope name in the `#pragma link` directive.

Comment: I already tried that but then I have a linker error:
"[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'HtmlHelpA' referenced from D:\CPP PROJEKTI\HELP & APP\WIN32\DEBUG\HTMLHELPVIEWER.OBJ"

Comment: I suspect the solution is to use the unit scope name. Try `#pragma link "Vcl.HTMLHelpViewer"`. This Emba forum post appears to have the same symptoms that you report: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=413904